# Remove Dot From the Y-axis Morris Line Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

I have implemented the `Morris Line Chart` with the following code and this is working well.

But I need some modifications in the second line name with the goal. You have seen dots come on every month. I want to remove these dots from that line so that I will be a straight line.

```
Morris.Line({
  element: 'line-chart',
  data: JSON.parse(GraphData),
  xkey: 'title',
  ykeys: ['goal', 'actual'],
  labels: ['Goal', 'Actual'],
  xLabelFormat: function(x) { // <--- x.getMonth() returns valid index
    var month = months[x.getMonth()];
    return month;
  },
  dateFormat: function(x) {
    var month = months[new Date(x).getMonth()];
    return month;
  },
  resize: true,
        lineColors: ['#ecb201', '#1B17BB'],
        gridTextFamily: "'Nunito', sans-serif",
        gridTextWeight: '300',
        gridTextSize: 11,
        gridTextColor: '#090b0d',
        pointSize: 4,
        lineWidth: 2,
        pointStrokeColors: ['#ffffff', '#ffffff'],
});
```

[image: Morris Line Chart]

Comment: i dont think that such parameter is available to fulfill your requirement, i guess you can use the CSS tricks

Comment: which css trick can you please explain ??

Comment: i am trying , , ,,  wait  for a while  , if i will get success wil sure update you

Comment: Thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 5):

Try to change pointSize to 0. Set pointSiZe: 0 at the begining

```
Morris.Line({
    element: 'line-chart',
    pointSize: 0, ....
)}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer as you can see i want only the second line to have no dots. but dots will appear in first line

Comment: So you need a specify your series data and set property pointSize for each series.

Answer (score 1):

use this script after you render the chart.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('circle[fill="#ecb201"]').each(function(i,el) {
            //console.log($(this).attr("r" , 0));
            $(this).removeAttr("r");
            $(this).removeAttr("cy");
            $(this).removeAttr("cx");

        });
    });
```

but on hover it will show those points again . thats the problem only.

Comment: I want only second line to be straight not the both. 
Thanks for the answer

Comment: This is looking nice but the on hover  points again occurs. If you will help me in this i will be much thankful to you

Comment: thats appreciating Sir
I am also trying to get the hover style

Comment: @UmairKhan It's Done.. check the Answer..  :-)